# Bootstrap Tabs - Prevent scrolling to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

This is the layout of my tabs. T1 and T2 are normal tab section. There is cascading tabs inside T3. Please find the markup below:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#T1">Tab1</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#T2">Tab2</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#T3">Tab3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="T2">
        Tab 2 Content...
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="T3">
            <div class="tabbable tabs-left">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                             <li class="active"><a href="#Chart" data-toggle="tab">Chart</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="#Report" data-toggle="tab">Reports</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active">
                                Chart Content...
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" style="float: right;width: 96%;">
                                Report Content...
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue is while clicking on T3 the page is scrolling up. Also in the JS side i'm calling the preventDefault method as shown below:

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
}
```

I think cascading tab inside T3 is causing the problem. How can we disable the default behavior of those tabs/links? Any thoughts on this...

Answer (score 52):

You can use: 
`<a data-target="#home">`
instead of `<a href="#home">`

See here for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/RPSmedia/K9LpL/1154/

Comment: In Bootstrap 5, the attribute is `data-bs-target`.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this by adding e.stopImmediatePropagation(); to the event handler:

```
$('.nav-tabs li a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  $(this).tab('show');
});
```

Comment: this is the answer im looking for

Answer (score 0):

It works Fine in Bootstrap versions less than 3. And in Bootstrap 3 you have to include CSS styles for tab-left and tab-right

i have created a fiddle check out

```
    <div class="tabbable tabs-left" style="margin-top:10px;">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#lA" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#lB" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#lC" data-toggle="tab">Section 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="lA">
                <p>I'm in Section A.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="lB">
                <p>Howdy, I'm in Section B.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="lC">
                <p>What up girl, this is Section C.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9CDMh/

Comment: The tabs are all working fine. The issue is while clicking the tab (having tab-left class, in my example, it is T3) the screen is scrolling up. Also I'm using Bootstrap v2.0.4

Comment: did you try using the Latest bootstrap version ?

Comment: tried to use the latest version of bootstrap, but the whole site is breaking.

Comment: send your
 jsfiddle link